# Question about field quantization

Tags: photons, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

I'm reading a paper by Rubin, Klyshko, Shih and Sergienko titled "Theory of two-photon entanglement in type_II optical parametric down-conversion", 1994 ([link to the paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.50.5122)).  I'm stumped by equation B2 in appendix B.  It looks like a product of an annihilation and a creation operator has been replaced by a dot product of two polarization vectors.  What allows you to make this substitution?

Answer (score 1):

In (B2) we take the state that is a superposition of the vacuum and some two-particle state (6),
\begin{equation}
|\Psi\rangle=|0\rangle+\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'}}F_{\mathbf{k}\mathbf{k'}}a^\dagger_{x\mathbf{k}}a^\dagger_{y\mathbf{k'}}
\end{equation}
and then act on it with the positive frequency part of the electric field operator. The definition for the standard polarizations $j=o,e$ are given in (2),
\begin{equation}
E_j^{(+)}=\sum_{\mathbf{k}} E_{j\mathbf{k}} a_{j\mathbf{k}} \exp\Bigl[i(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-\omega_{j\mathbf{k}}t)\Bigr]
\end{equation}
where $E_{j\mathbf{k}}$ are given by (3) which I'm too lazy to reproduce here. For the arbitrary polarization vector $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1$ we can construct it as,
\begin{equation}
E_1^{(+)}=(\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1\cdot\hat{\mathbf{e}}_o)E_o^{(+)}+(\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1\cdot\hat{\mathbf{e}}_e)E_e^{(+)}
\end{equation}
Note that the resulting $E_1^{(+)}$ is nothing more than a superposition of the annihilation operators. Then acting on $|\Psi\rangle$ it cancels the vacuum contribution and eats one of the creation operators in the two-particle state. Just before (6) they choose $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_o=\hat{\mathbf{e}}_x$ and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_e=\hat{\mathbf{e}}_y$ and thus $E_o^{(+)}$ eats $a^\dagger_{x\mathbf{k}}$ whereas $E_e^{(+)}$ eats $a^\dagger_{y\mathbf{k'}}$

P/S: This question is not really on the experimental physics:)

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  Can you provide some detail about how the annihilation operator eats the creation operator?

Comment: @rjlogan Basically it goes like that. The commutation relation is $[a,a^\dagger]=1$. 
So $aa^\dagger|0\rangle = |0\rangle + a^\dagger a|0\rangle$ but $a|0\rangle=0$ so the second term disappears. What is your experience with the quantum harmonic oscillator and with the quantum optics (it basically all about many oscillators)? You need some basis in that before you dive in that paper